# Check socket with select() before using send()

Tags: c++, sockets, select

I am using my client to write to the server. I want to check to see if the socket is open for writing in my client, and if it is not ready for 10s after a connection has been established, then I want to print an error message and exit my client due to timeout.

The client works properly with just the send function, and I am able to transfer a file from the client to the server. However, when I implemented the select() feature, the client now will just time out with sel_value being set to 0.

To make it easier to read, I have removed my code that does the send feature because there is some additional logic for reading stuff into a buffer.

```
//set up select for sending
fd_set wfds;
struct timeval timeout;
while (1) {
    FD_ZERO(&wfds);
    FD_SET(sockfd, &wfds);

    timeout.tv_sec = 10;
    timeout.tv_usec = 0; //no us

    int sel_value = select(sockfd+1, &wfds, NULL, NULL, &timeout);
    cout<<"sel_value is: "<<sel_value<<endl;
    if(sel_value == -1){
        perror("select");

    }else if(sel_value == 0){
        printf("Timeout. Cannot send for 10s \n");
        break;
    }
    else{
        if(FD_ISSET(sockfd, &wfds)){
            //my code never reaches this point, but here is where we send
            //code to send stuff
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Prefer [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) to the old `select`. Read about [C10k problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C10k_problem)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're doing this back to front. You should just do the send, and only select for writability if the send incurred EAGAIN/EWOULDBLOCK. A socket is almost always ready to write, except when the socket send buffer is full. Your way you're doubling system calls and adding latency.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. If I do the send, then I need to check to see if errno=EAGAIN || errno = EWOULDBLOCK. If errno is one of these values, do I try to resend? Is one way to do this by calling select() and then reading its return value: if it's ready to write, then I can just do continue() and then come back to the send in the loop?

Comment: I've answered that. If `errno` is EAGAIN/EWOULDBLOCK, you select.

Comment: Does what you're saying work even if my socket is blocking?

Comment: Nope. Doesn't work with blocking. I made the socket non-blocking and everything is great. Thanks!

Comment: If the socket is blocking it will block *instead* of incurring EAGAIN/EWOULDBLOCK.

Answer (score 1):

for write set the third field, i.e:

```
select(sockfd+1, NULL, &wfds, NULL, &timeout);
```