# Linux select() not blocking

Tags: c, linux, select, system-calls, file-handling

I'm trying to understand the difference between select() and poll() better. For this I tried to implement a simple program that will open a file as write-only, add its file descriptor to the read set and than execute select in hopes that the function will block until the read permission is granted.
As this didnt work (and as far as I understood, this is intended behaviour) I tried to block access to the file using flock before the select() executen. Still, the program did not block its execution.

My sample code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <poll.h>
#include <sys/file.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/select.h>


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
   printf("[+] Select minimal example\n");
   int max_number_fds = FOPEN_MAX;
   int select_return;
   int cnt_pollfds;
   struct pollfd pfds_array[max_number_fds];
   struct pollfd *pfds = pfds_array;

   fd_set fds;
   int fd_file = open("./poll_text.txt",  O_WRONLY);

   struct timeval tv;
   tv.tv_sec = 10;
   tv.tv_usec = 0;

   printf("\t[+] Textfile fd: %d\n", fd_file);

   //create and set fds set    
   FD_ZERO(&fds);
   FD_SET(fd_file, &fds);

   printf("[+] Locking file descriptor!\n");
   if(flock(fd_file,LOCK_EX) == -1)
   {
       int error_nr = errno;
       printf("\t[+] Errno: %d\n", error_nr);
   }  

   printf("[+] Executing select()\n");
   select_return = select(fd_file+1, &fds, NULL, NULL, &tv);
   if(select_return == -1){
       int error_nr = errno;
       printf("[+] Select Errno: %d\n", error_nr);
   }

   printf("[+] Select return: %d\n", select_return); 
 }
```

Can anybody see my error in this code? Also: I first tried to execute this code with two FDs added to the read list. When trying to lock them I had to use flock(fd_file,LOCK_SH) as I cannot exclusively lock two FDs with LOCK_EX. Is there a difference on how to lock two FDs of the same file (compared to only one fd)

I'm also not sure why select will not block when a file, that is added to the Read-set is opened as Write-Only. The program can never (without a permission change) read data from the fd, so in my understanding select should block the execution, right?

As a clarification: My "problem" I want to solve is that I have to check if I'm able to replace existing select() calls with poll() (existing in terms of: i will not re-write the select() call code, but will have access to the arguments of select.). To check this, I wanted to implement a test that will force select to block its execution, so I can later check if poll will act the same way (when given similar instructions, i.e. the same FDs to check).

So my "workflow" would be: write tests for different select behaviors (i.e. block and not block), write similar tests for poll (also block, not block) and check if/how poll can be forced do exactly what select is doing.

Thank you for any hints!

Comment: You open the file as write-only. And you poll using `select` to check if it's readable, which it will never be. Please read [the `select` manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html).

Comment: And please take some time to refresh [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Then edit your question to include the expected and actual output you get from your program.

Comment: Yes, thats why i think select() should block right (which is exactly what I'm trying to achieve)? Also, when I set the permission RW or RDONLY select is still not blocking. Not sure where my logic error is here

Comment: `select` is telling you that there is a read status you should check on the file descriptor. Since the file is write only, the read status may be an error or EOF. Either way, once that status is acknowledged, you remove it from the fd set.

Comment: Ok, but then when I changed the permission to RDONLY and locked it with flock, select should not be able to say that RD is possible. According to man: "select() allow a program to monitor multiple  file  descriptors,  waiting  until one or more of the file descriptors become "ready" for some class of I/O operation (e.g.,  input  possible)."
The file is locked, and therefore it is not ready so I/O (in my case reading) right?

Comment: The lock is to make other processes unable to read from or write to the file. But your own process still can read from or write to the file.

Comment: Why on earth are you using `select()` on a file? What exactly are your expectations of this code?

Comment: I've added an explaination above. I used a (text) file as it was the first type that came to my mind. If I can test selects' blocking behavior better with another file type, feel free to recomment me one. Currently I'm checking if a socket file would be more suitable

Comment: Err, a socket? That's what it's really for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When `select` tells you that a file descriptor is ready for reading, this doesn't necessarily mean that you can read data. It only means that a `read` call will not block. A `read` call will also not block when it returns an EOF or error condition.

In your case I expect that `read` will immediately return -1 and set `errno` to `EBADF` (fd is not a valid file descriptor or is not open for reading) or maybe `EINVAL` (fd is attached to an object which is unsuitable for reading...)

**Edit:** Additional information as requested in a comment:

A file can be in a blocking state if a physical operation is needed that will take some time, e.g. if the read buffer is empty and (new) data has to be read from the disk, if the file is connected to a terminal and the user has not yet entered any (more) data or if the file is a socket or a pipe and a `read` would have to wait for (new) data to arrive...

The same applies for `write`: If the send buffer is full, a `write` will block. If the remaining space in the send buffer is smaller than your amount of data, it may write only the part that currently fits into the buffer.

If you set a file to non-blocking mode, a `read` or `write` will not block but tell you that it **would** block.

If you want to have a blocking situation for testing purposes, you need control over the process or hardware that provides or consumes the data. I suggest to use `read` from a terminal (`stdin`) when you don't enter any data or from a pipe where the writing process does not write any data. You can also fill the write buffer on a pipe when the reading process does not read from it.

Comment: Ok I see. But is there a way to force select to be blocked then? Or how can a file be set to a "blocking state"? And thanks for the explanation!

Comment: Would it be possible to set a socket fd to "not ready" by filling its send-buffer with data, as stated in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43552960/check-socket-with-select-before-using-send)?

Comment: You should explain what you want to achieve. You seem to ask about a technical solution but we don't know which problem you want to solve.

Comment: You're right: so as stated above I try to understand the difference between poll and select. My goal (as part of a project) is to map existing select calls to poll. For this i wanted to implement a test that will force select to block its execution, so I can later check if poll will act the same way (when given similar instructions, i.e. the same FDs to check).

So my "workflow" would be: write tests for different select behaviors (i.e. block and not block), write similar tests for poll (also block, not block) and check if/how poll can be forced do exactly what select is doing

Comment: @MajorasKid Please add all clarification or explanation **to the question** instead of writing comments.

Comment: Just saw your edit. I will test that. But it sounds as if thats exactly what I needed. Thanks in advance